# how will i get two different property files in same java class which is transulated to spanish language?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java developer. I have wrote a java class file in eclipse for getting all key value pairs of spanish property file which as below:

```
   public class ResoucreBundleproperties {

      static void iterateKeys(Locale currentLocale) {

      ResourceBundle labels = 
         ResourceBundle.getBundle("xxxx_ar_SP",currentLocale);

      Enumeration<String> bundleKeys = labels.getKeys();

      while (bundleKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
         String key = (String)bundleKeys.nextElement();
         String value  = labels.getString(key);
         System.out.println("key = " + key + ", " +
           "value = " + value);
      }

   } 
   public static  void main(String[] args) {

      Locale[] supportedLocales = {
         new Locale("SP","SPANISH"),
                 Locale.ENGLISH
      };


      iterateKeys(supportedLocales[0]);
      System.out.println();
   }
```

I got a output of `xxxx.ar_SP.properties` with all keys and values.

Now I have another two more files of properties like `yyyy_ar_SP.properties` and `zzzz_ar_SP.properties`.

(pls tell me if any mistakes I done or u cant get me).

Question 1: now how will I get all these two property files (`xxxx_ar_SP.properties,yyyy_ar_SP.properties,zzzz_ar_SP.properties`) in the same java class. Is that possible?

Question 2: how to convert the spanish property files to unicode escapes?

Comment: please use proper english, punctuation marks, capital letters, etc. It is extremely diffcult to read your question.

Comment: i am sorry.. i have two property files like xxxx_ar_SP.properties and yyyy_ar_SP.properties which i transulated to SPANISH Language.i want to know how will i code for two property files of SPANISH Language in the same java class... now am i correct in english..?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.

You have a default properties file `xxxxx.properties`, one language specific properties file `xxxxx_es.properties`, and if you want regional variations, then you add the country prefix `xxxxx_es_ES.properties`.

The resource bundle will use the locale you provided, or the default one, and will do:

1) If a file for the language or language+country is found, use it. It will use the more specific value for a property; if your locale is "es_ES" and you provided a value in "xxxxx_es_ES", that one is used, otherwise (if your locale is "es_AR" and no `xxxxx_es_AR.properties` exists, or if your locale is `es_ES` but you did not define the value in `xxxxx_es_ES.properties`), then it will search the value in `xxxxx_es.properties`.

2) If your locale is not found, it will use the default (no locale) properties file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple property files for a specific locale. In order to load these into one `Properties` object you can do the following:

```
static void loadProperties(Locale currentLocale, String... propertyFileNames){
  for(String propertyFileName : propertyFileNames)
  {
     ResourceBundle labels =
           ResourceBundle.getBundle(propertyFileName ,currentLocale);

     Enumeration<String> bundleKeys = labels.getKeys();

     while (bundleKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String)bundleKeys.nextElement();
        String value  = labels.getString(key);
        System.out.println("key = " + key + ", " +
              "value = " + value);
        props.put(key, value);
     }
  }
}
```

Where `props` is a static `java.util.Properties` object.

Not sure about question 2 I'll have to look around a bit.

Comment: where will i initialize PropertyFileNames.?

Comment: Just hand the method whatever property files you are interested in loading. For example `loadProperties(supportedLocales[0], "xxxx", "zzzz")` could be called from your main method. Also take into consideration the other answer as those points are valid.